# How can I make the cross curve visible in LineChart by code?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

When I touched the LineChart view and select one point, a cross curve will be displayed, but How can I do this by code? any API? thx

Answer (score 1):

I think what you expect to draw is [`LimitLine`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/LimitLine.java)

Here is the example of usage: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis#limit-lines

Both axis (X and Y) have an option to add it to chart:

```
public void addLimitLine(LimitLine l)
```

Example is here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis#example-code